# Función Ordenar Excel VB.Net

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net, excel

Uso las librerías de Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Lo que hago es ir introduciendo alarmas en un excel Lo que no sé hacer es que mediante el vb.net me ordené las alarmas por día y hora, de tal forma que me muestre de la última alarma introducida a la primera. No puedo usar macros, porque ya he probado a usar una plantilla y me da errores porque en el otro PC usan Open Office.
Se os ocurre alguna solución. Muchas gracias por todo. Un saludo.

Os adjunto el código de la inserción de las alarmas.

```
Public Sub GuardarAlarmas()
        'Creo la carpeta donde almacenare las alarmas de origen y la ruta del archivo del origen
        Dim MES = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM")
        Dim rutaDirectorioOrigen = FormMain.rutaHistoricoAlarmasOrigen + "Año " + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(rutaDirectorioOrigen)
        Dim rutaArchivoOrigen As String = rutaDirectorioOrigen + "\Alarmas " + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString + "_" + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString + "_" + MonthName(MES.ToUpper) + ".xlsm"
        'Creo la carpeta donde almacenaré las alarmas de destino y la ruta del archivo del destino
        Dim rutaDirectorioDestino = FormMain.rutaHistoricoAlarmasDestino + "Año " + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(rutaDirectorioDestino)
        Dim rutaArchivoDestino As String = rutaDirectorioDestino + "\Alarmas " + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString + "_" + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString + "_" + MonthName(MES.ToUpper) + ".xlsm"
        'Aqui declaro el objeto Aplicación excel, su libro y su hoja
        Dim oExcel As Object
        Dim oBook As Excel.Workbook
        Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
        'Inicializo la aplicacion Excel
        oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        'Si no existe el archivo de origen en excel, cojo la plantilla creada en excel y luego creo el Archivo de Ruta de Origen
        If Not File.Exists(rutaArchivoOrigen) Then
            oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FormMain.rutaHistoricoAlarmasOrigen + "PlantillaExcel.xlsm", ReadOnly:=False)
            oBook.SaveAs(Filename:=rutaArchivoOrigen, AccessMode:=3, ConflictResolution:=2, Local:=True)
            oBook.Close()
        End If
        'Si no existe el archivo de origen abro ese archivo
        If File.Exists(rutaArchivoOrigen) Then
            oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=rutaArchivoOrigen, ReadOnly:=False)
        End If
        'Elijo la primera hoja del excel
        oSheet = oExcel.Worksheets(1)
        'Cuento las líneas escritas en cada fila y le pongo un +6 porque empiezo en B6 y si quiero escribir en B7,B8 y viceversa necesito ponerle el +6
        Dim paco = oSheet.Range("B6").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 6
        'Aquí recojo el texto de estado, descripción, hora y día
        Me.Label_Texto_Alarma.Text = arrayTexto(Me.Label_Numero_Alarma.Text)
        Dim estado = Me.Label_Estado_Alarma.Text
        Dim descrip = Me.Label_Texto_Alarma.Text
        Dim hora = TimeOfDay
        Dim dia = Format(Now, "dd/MM")
        'Introduzco los datos de la alarma
        oSheet.Range("B" + paco.ToString).Value = dia
        oSheet.Range("C" + paco.ToString).Value = hora
        oSheet.Range("D" + paco.ToString).Value = estado
        oSheet.Range("E" + paco.ToString).Value = descrip
        'Si el estado es ACTIVA, el color será rojo. Si es inactiva será Verde y si es acusada será NARANJA
        If (estado.Equals("ACTIVA")) Then
            oSheet.Range("B" + paco.ToString + ":E" + paco.ToString).Font.Color = Color.Red
        End If
        If (estado.Equals("INACTIVA")) Then
            oSheet.Range("B" + paco.ToString + ":E" + paco.ToString).Font.Color = Color.Green
        End If
        If (estado.Equals("ACUSADA")) Then
            oSheet.Range("B" + paco.ToString + ":E" + paco.ToString).Font.Color = Color.Orange
        End If
        'Aquí pongo un borde negro en el Excel
        Dim Range = oSheet.Range("B" + paco.ToString + ":E" + paco.ToString)
        Range.Borders.Color = Color.Black
        oSheet.UsedRange.Select()
        oSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear()
        oSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add(oSheet.UsedRange.Columns("B"), Excel.XlSortOn.xlSortOnValues, Excel.XlSortOrder.xlDescending, System.Type.Missing, Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal)
        oSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add(oSheet.UsedRange.Columns("C"), Excel.XlSortOn.xlSortOnValues, Excel.XlSortOrder.xlDescending, System.Type.Missing, Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal)
        Dim sort = oSheet.Sort
        sort.SetRange(oSheet.UsedRange)
        sort.Header = Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlYes
        sort.MatchCase = False
        sort.Orientation = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSortOrientation.xlSortColumns
        sort.SortMethod = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSortMethod.xlPinYin
        sort.Apply()
        Try
            'Aquí uso el DisplayAlerts, para que directamente me confirme que deseo guardar el archivo.
            oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
            'Aquí guardo todos los datos introducidos
            oBook.SaveAs(Filename:=rutaArchivoOrigen, AccessMode:=3, ConflictResolution:=2, Local:=True)
            oBook.SaveAs(Filename:=rutaArchivoDestino, AccessMode:=3, ConflictResolution:=2, Local:=True)
            'Aquí pongo el DisplayAlerts a true, por si acaso este queda invalidado en toda la aplicación.
            oExcel.DisplayAlerts = True
            oBook.Close()
            oExcel.Quit()
        Catch
            'Si hubiese algún error en excel, mataría todos los procesos.
            Dim pListOfProcesses() As Process
            Dim pExcelProcess As System.Diagnostics.Process
            pListOfProcesses = pExcelProcess.GetProcesses
            For Each pExcelProcess In pListOfProcesses
                If pExcelProcess.ProcessName.ToUpper = "EXCEL" Then
                    pExcelProcess.Kill()
                End If
            Next
        End Try
    End Sub
    Public WithEvents Label_Hora_Alarma As System.Windows.Forms.Label
End Class
```

[Descargar Excel Alarmas](https://www.mediafire.com/file/xlvo6dj12yrecmh/Alarmas+2021_11_noviembre.xlsm/file)

Comment: Hola amigo, Bienvenido al Sitio, He verificado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask], Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], He visto que has agregado Imágenes, es preferible que tus ejemplos sean en texto y facilites el uso del mismo, También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: Hola, he adjuntado un trozo de código de como hago la inserción con la librería de Microsoft Excel en vb.net. Así ya arreglaría la pregunta? Aunque realmente lo que estoy buscando es ordenar por fecha y hora. Por eso escribí un texto explicando el problema.

Comment: las dos cosas son importante.

Comment: Alguien puede probar mi código. He añadido la función de ordenado para ordenar la columna B y la C, pero me es imposible que me las ordene. La columna B y C son para ordenar por Fecha y por Hora. En teoría la fecha más antigua y la hora mas alta

Answer (score -2):

Os dejo aquí la solucion, al final he conseguido hacer el ordenado como quería. Contento con el resultado.

```
  Public Sub GuardarAlarmas()
        'Creo la carpeta donde almacenare las alarmas de origen y la ruta del archivo del origen
        Dim MES = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM")
        Dim rutaDirectorioOrigen = FormMain.rutaHistoricoAlarmasOrigen + "Año " + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(rutaDirectorioOrigen)
        Dim rutaArchivoOrigen As String = rutaDirectorioOrigen + "\Alarmas " + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString + "_" + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString + "_" + MonthName(MES.ToUpper) + ".xlsm"
        'Creo la carpeta donde almacenaré las alarmas de destino y la ruta del archivo del destino
        Dim rutaDirectorioDestino = FormMain.rutaHistoricoAlarmasDestino + "Año " + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(rutaDirectorioDestino)
        Dim rutaArchivoDestino As String = rutaDirectorioDestino + "\Alarmas " + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString + "_" + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString + "_" + MonthName(MES.ToUpper) + ".xlsm"
        'Aqui declaro el objeto Aplicación excel, su libro y su hoja
        Dim oExcel As Object
        Dim oBook As Excel.Workbook
        Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
        'Inicializo la aplicacion Excel
        oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        'Si no existe el archivo de origen en excel, cojo la plantilla creada en excel y luego creo el Archivo de Ruta de Origen
        If Not File.Exists(rutaArchivoOrigen) Then
            oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FormMain.rutaHistoricoAlarmasOrigen + "PlantillaExcel.xlsm", ReadOnly:=False)
            oBook.SaveAs(Filename:=rutaArchivoOrigen, AccessMode:=3, ConflictResolution:=2, Local:=True)
            oBook.Close()
        End If
        'Si no existe el archivo de origen abro ese archivo
        If File.Exists(rutaArchivoOrigen) Then
            oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=rutaArchivoOrigen, ReadOnly:=False)
        End If
        'Elijo la primera hoja del excel
        oSheet = oExcel.Worksheets(1)
        'Cuento las líneas escritas en cada fila y le pongo un +6 porque empiezo en B6 y si quiero escribir en B7,B8 y viceversa necesito ponerle el +6
        Dim paco = oSheet.Range("B6").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1
        'Aquí recojo el texto de estado, descripción, hora y día
        Me.Label_Texto_Alarma.Text = arrayTexto(Me.Label_Numero_Alarma.Text)
        Dim estado = Me.Label_Estado_Alarma.Text
        Dim descrip = Me.Label_Texto_Alarma.Text
        Dim hora = TimeOfDay
        Dim dia = Date.Today.Day.ToString
        'Introduzco los datos de la alarma
        oSheet.Range("B" + paco.ToString).Value = dia
        oSheet.Range("C" + paco.ToString).Value = hora
        oSheet.Range("D" + paco.ToString).Value = estado
        oSheet.Range("E" + paco.ToString).Value = descrip
        'Si el estado es ACTIVA, el color será rojo. Si es inactiva será Verde y si es acusada será NARANJA
        If (estado.Equals("ACTIVA")) Then
            oSheet.Range("B" + paco.ToString + ":E" + paco.ToString).Font.Color = Color.Red
        End If
        If (estado.Equals("INACTIVA")) Then
            oSheet.Range("B" + paco.ToString + ":E" + paco.ToString).Font.Color = Color.Green
        End If
        If (estado.Equals("ACUSADA")) Then
            oSheet.Range("B" + paco.ToString + ":E" + paco.ToString).Font.Color = Color.Orange
        End If
        'Aquí pongo un borde negro en el Excel
        Dim rangos = oSheet.Range("B" + paco.ToString + ":E" + paco.ToString)
        rangos.Borders.Color = Color.Black
        oSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear()
        oSheet.UsedRange.Select()
        oSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add(oSheet.Range("B6:B1200"), Excel.XlSortOn.xlSortOnValues, Excel.XlSortOrder.xlDescending, System.Type.Missing, Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal)
        oSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add(oSheet.Range("C6:C1200"), Excel.XlSortOn.xlSortOnValues, Excel.XlSortOrder.xlDescending, System.Type.Missing, Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal)
        Dim sort = oSheet.Sort
        sort.SetRange(oSheet.Range("B6:E1200"))
        sort.Header = Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlYes
        sort.MatchCase = False
        sort.Orientation = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSortOrientation.xlSortColumns
        sort.SortMethod = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSortMethod.xlPinYin
        sort.Apply()
        Try
            'Aquí uso el DisplayAlerts, para que directamente me confirme que deseo guardar el archivo.
            oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
            'Aquí guardo todos los datos introducidos
            oBook.SaveAs(Filename:=rutaArchivoOrigen, AccessMode:=3, ConflictResolution:=2, Local:=True)
            oBook.SaveAs(Filename:=rutaArchivoDestino, AccessMode:=3, ConflictResolution:=2, Local:=True)
            'Aquí pongo el DisplayAlerts a true, por si acaso este queda invalidado en toda la aplicación.
            oExcel.DisplayAlerts = True
            oBook.Close()
            oExcel.Quit()
        Catch
            'Si hubiese algún error en excel, mataría todos los procesos.
            Dim pListOfProcesses() As Process
            Dim pExcelProcess As System.Diagnostics.Process
            pListOfProcesses = pExcelProcess.GetProcesses
            For Each pExcelProcess In pListOfProcesses
                If pExcelProcess.ProcessName.ToUpper = "EXCEL" Then
                    pExcelProcess.Kill()
                End If
            Next
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: ¿Qué utilidad tiene esto? ¿En qué se diferencia del original?

Comment: La utilidad que tiene es introducir datos en un Excel y ordenarlos. En mi caso por fecha y hora.

Comment: Donde esta el orden? cual es la parte que ordena? que sentido tiene este codigo con respecto al otro? cual era el problema del otro?